# How to create Django form for a photo grid?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to create a Django form that will contain a grid of one to ten photos.  There will be two radio button groups below each photo, one to indicate if the viewer approves or rejects that photo and a second group to indicate if the photo needs to be rotated.  The "Approve" and "No" radio buttons will be checked by default:

```
(photo1)
Approve or reject?  Approve (x)  Reject( )
Rotate?  No (x)  Left ( )  Right ( )  Flip ( )

(photo2)
Approve or reject?  Approve (x)  Reject( )
Rotate?  No (x)  Left ( )  Right ( )  Flip ( )

(more photos...)
```

When the viewer submits the form, I want to examine the name of each photo (e.g. "foobar.jpg") and its radio buttons to determine whether it was approved or rejected and whether or not it needs to be rotated.  The photo names are all contained in a Python list that I populate by identifying the names of the photos in a particular directory.

I don't quite understand how to define a form where you have multiple identical form "components" (in this case photo plus radio buttons) all within the same form.  I also don't understand how to merge the photo names into the form so I can display the photos.  Should each photo's name go in a hidden field?  I didn't see anything in the Django docs that addresses this situation.

This doesn't seem to be a job for Django Formsets.  Also, I don't want to use ModelForms.  Thanks for your help.

Here are abbreviated versions of my view, form, and template:

```
# views.py
def review_photos(request, template):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReviewPhotosForm(request.POST)  # Need another arg?
        if form.is_valid():
            # Extract each photo name and examine its corresponding radio buttons.
            pass
    else:
        photo_names = list_all_files_in_dir("/path/to/photo/dir")
        form = ReviewPhotosForm(photo_names=photo_names)
    return render_to_response(template, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# forms.py
class ReviewPhotosForm(forms.Form):
    DECISION_CHOICES = ( ('approve', 'Approve'), ('reject', 'Reject') )
    ROTATE_CHOICES = ( ('none,', 'None'), ('right', 'Right'), ('left', 'Left'), ('flip', 'Flip') )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        photo_names = kwargs.pop('photo_names')
        super(ReviewPhotosForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for name in photo_names:
            self.fields[???] = forms.ChoiceField(
                label = 'Approve or reject?',
                choices = self.DECISION_CHOICES,
                widget = forms.RadioSelect(renderer=widget.HorizontalRadioRenderer),
                initial = 'approve')

            self.fields[???] = forms.ChoiceField(
                label = 'Rotate?',
                choices = self.ROTATE_CHOICES,
                widget = forms.RadioSelect(renderer=widget.HorizontalRadioRenderer),
                initial = 'none')

# review_photos.html
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
        <!-- How do I insert each photo's name into the form? -->
        {% for field in form %}
        <li>
            <img src="{{ photo_name }}" />  <!-- ??? -->
            <div id="decision">
                {{ ???.label }}
                {{ ??? }}
            </div>
            <div id="rotate">
                {{ ???.label }}
                {{ ??? }}
            </div>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the contrary, this is exactly a job for formsets: 'multiple identical form "components" all within the same form' is precisely what they are.

```
class ReviewPhotosForm(forms.Form):
    DECISION_CHOICES = ( ('approve', 'Approve'), ('reject', 'Reject') )
    ROTATE_CHOICES = ( ('none,', 'None'), ('right', 'Right'), ('left', 'Left'), ('flip', 'Flip') )

    # hidden field to associate radio buttons with a photo
    photo_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    approve = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Approve or reject?',
        choices=self.DECISION_CHOICES,
         widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=widget.HorizontalRadioRenderer),
        initial='approve')

    rotate = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Rotate?',
        choices=self.ROTATE_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=widget.HorizontalRadioRenderer),
        initial='none')
```

view:

```
def review_photos(request, template):
    ReviewPhotosFormSet = formset_factory(ReviewPhotosForm, extra=0)

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = ReviewPhotosFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            # list of photos and radio buttons is in formset.cleaned_data
            pass
    else:
        photo_names = list_all_files_in_dir("/path/to/photo/dir")
        initial_data = [{'photo_name': name} for name in photo_names]

        form = ReviewPhotosForm(initial=initial_data)
    return render(request template, {'formset': formset})
```

template:

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <ul>
        {% for form in formset %}
        <li> {{ form.photo_name }}
            <img src="{{ form.photo_name.value }}" />
            <div id="decision">
                {{ form.decision.label_tag }}
                {{ form.decision }}
                {{ form.decision.errors }}
            </div>
            <div id="rotate">
                {{ form.rotate.label_tag }}
                {{ form.rotate }}
                {{ form.rotate.errors }}
            </div>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'm very grateful for your help.  The Django Formsets docs confused me because they refer to "multiple forms on the same page" and I think of a form as including a Submit button.  To me, this meant that using formsets would mean there would be multiple Submit buttons which is not the case for my form.  There were only two minor typos in your view.  One, the view needs to import formset_factory from django.forms.formsets.  Two, the else block should read "formset = ReviewPhotosFormSet(initial=...)" instead of "form = ReviewPhotosForm(...)"